# Sorting a "black box" query in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I use a query like this one a lot:

```
def activityQuery(inActivity, inOrder='time'):
    a1 = gDB.session.query(Activity.unitID, Activity.activity, func.max(Activity.occurredAt).label("maxOA")) \
        .group_by(Activity.unitID) \
        .subquery()
    a2 = aliased(Activity, name="a2")
    u = aliased(Unit, name="u")
    q = gDB.session.query(u).select_from(a1) \
        .join(a2, and_(a2.unitID == a1.c.unit_id, a2.occurredAt == a1.c.maxOA)) \
        .join(u, u.id == a2.unitID).filter(a2.activity.in_(inActivity))

    if inOrder == 'time':
        q = q.order_by(a2.occurredAt)
    elif inOrder == 'address':
        q = q.order_by(u.street, u.unitNumber)
    return q
```

As you can see, I'm passing an argument to indicate the desired sort, but I'd really like to just specify the sort after calling `activityQuery()`. Is this possible? Obviously, symbols like `a2` and `u` are out of scope outside of this call. Is there another way to specify how to order the resulting query? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `activityQuery` accept a callable as *inOrder*:

```
def timeOrder(q, u, a1, a2):
    return q.order_by(a2.occurredAt)


def addressOrder(q, u, a1, a2):
    return q.order_by(u.street, u.unitNumber)


def activityQuery(inActivity, inOrder=timeOrder):
    a1 = gDB.session.query(Activity.unitID,
                           Activity.activity,
                           func.max(Activity.occurredAt).label("maxOA")) \
        .group_by(Activity.unitID) \
        .subquery()

    a2 = aliased(Activity, name="a2")
    u = aliased(Unit, name="u")

    q = gDB.session.query(u).select_from(a1) \
        .join(a2, and_(a2.unitID == a1.c.unit_id,
                       a2.occurredAt == a1.c.maxOA)) \
        .join(u, u.id == a2.unitID) \
        .filter(a2.activity.in_(inActivity))

    return inOrder(q, u, a1, a2)

activityQuery(..., inOrder=addressOrder)
```

Comment: So, a more concise way to call it would be `activityQuery(..., inOrder = lambda q, u, a1, a2: return q.order_by(a2.occurredAt))`?


Still more verbose than I'd like, but I'll give that a shot. Thank you.

Comment: If you remove the return, then yes, since a lambda can only contain a single expression, and `return ...` is a statement. Personally I like how the named functions make the code readable (In what order? address order!), but to each of his own.